# Count occurrence of list of words in multiple files

Tags: bash

I have a .txt with a list of words (gene names, separated with newlines) and I want to count their occurrences in multiple files in multiple folders.

Folders are like this :
MainFolder/family_ID/variants/FILE.table

One folder for each family.

I tried with grep, it does count but it outputs one line per file :

```
WDFY3 0
WDFY3 0
WDFY3 1
WDFY3 0
WDFY3 0
KMT2C 1
KMT2C 0
KMT2C 0
KMT2C 0
KMT2C 0
```

I want it that way :

```
WDFY3 1
KMT2C 1
```

Here's the code I used :

```
while read p; do
    grep -FRchi "$p" --include \*.FILE.table | sed "s/^/$p /" >> /MyData/MainFolder/count.txt
done < /MyData/Resources/gene_list.txt
```

Is it possible with grep? Should I use awk/sed?

Thank you

Comment: Are the lines in `gene_list.txt` unique?

Comment: Take the output from you script and pipe it to awk '{ arry[$1]+=$2 } END { for (i in arry) { print i" "arry[i] } }'

Comment: Yes, one line for one gene, up to a total of 113

Comment: Thank you Raman, this is working

Comment: From an already deleted comment: _I should have mentioned that the lines are looking like this : 14 77493809 SNP SYNONYMOUS_CODING(LOW|SILENT|caG/caA|Q109|796|IRF2BPL||CODING|NM_024496.3|1|1) NA 13520.p1 C/C C/C C/T C/T So it prints the whole line after the count_ Would you mind posting some real lines of your data and tell which part of above data should be counted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the output from you script and pipe it to

```
awk '{ arry[$1]+=$2 } END { for (i in arry) { print i" "arry[i] } }'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make `grep` output all the lines, sort them and then count them:

```
#!/bin/bash

genes=/MyData/Resources/gene_list.txt

grep -RhioFf "$genes" --include 'FILE.table' | sort | uniq -c
```

This will output the count in the first column and the gene in the second.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the lines are looking like this :
14 77493809 SNP SYNONYMOUS_CODING(LOW|SILENT|caG/caA|Q109|796|IRF2BPL||CODING|NM_024496.3|1|1) NA 13520.p1 C/C C/C C/T C/T
So it prints the whole line after the count

Comment: @EmilCioran Updated with the new info.